# Related tables not saving in MVC application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following models -

```
public class RoleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int LastUpdateBy { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public State State { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<UserModel> UsersNotInRole { get; set; }
    public virtual int[] SelectedUsers { get; set; }

    public virtual List<RightModel> Rights { get; set; }
    public virtual List<RightModel> SelectedRights { get; set; }

    public RoleModel()
    {

    }
}

public class RightModel
{
    public string RightName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Assigned { get; set; }
}
```

From this, each role has a collection of rights assigned to them. From the following view, I wish to allow users to select a check box against each right they want to assign to the selected role. The view is loading the data correctly and checking the correct boxes, but when I press 'Save', the Rights list is null. Any ideas how I can correct this so that it removes all rights from the selected role, then re-assigned the required rights.

```
 @model Project.Core.Models.Roles.RoleModel
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_3">
                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Right Name</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var right in Model.Rights)
                                            {
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => right.RightName)</td>
                                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => right.Description)</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="success-toggle-button">
                                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => right.Assigned, new { @class = "toggle" })
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
```

and my controller -

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        RoleModel role = _roleService.GetById(id);

        if (role == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(role);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(RoleModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _roleService.Update(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

and my Update method in RoleService -

```
public void Update(RoleModel entity)
    {
        entity.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        entity.LastUpdateBy = 1;

        Role r = _roleRepository.FindById(entity.Id);

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<RoleModel, Role>();

        _roleRepository.Update(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(entity, r));
    }
```

and my repository update method -

```
 public void Update(Role role)
    {
        _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(role, EntityState.Modified);

        SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Please show us your `Update(Model model)` method of your Roleservice.

Comment: I have updated the question with this in

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related in any way to your problem but the [.Net Framework Constructor Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229060(v=vs.110).aspx) say "AVOID calling virtual members on an object inside its constructor."

EF uses virtual properties as "navigation properties" and will lazy-load any results as a result of a join on a foreign key - you don't appear to use the list in that class so [I would] leave out `Users = new List<UserModel>();`

Comment: Well, and now the `Update()` method of your repository. If you have more service layers: the method where your update actually happens.

Comment: @Sean I did notice this and have since removed this. However it has not resolved the issue. I have added the repository update method.

Comment: The MVC editor cannot process a `foreach` edit. Try a `for-loop` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user3153169 said in comments, for collections you will need to have your id/name for elements to be like RoleModel.Rights[i].Assigned for the automapper to find the elements.

So you should be using for loop as such

```
@for (int i = 0 ; i < Model.Rights.Count() ; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Rights[i].RightName)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Rights[i].Description)</td>
        <td>
            <div class="success-toggle-button">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Rights[i].Assigned, new { @class = "toggle" })
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```